# Updating custom output layers of an LSTM network

Tags: python, long-short-term-memory, keras, policy-gradients

I have a text generation task learning to predict the next word with an LSTM network with multiple output layers.
After the generation of a sentence has finished, I calculate a reward for the whole sentence and try to update the output layers participated in the generation (contributing layers get the calculated reward value, others get 0).
My problem is that even if I update only the selected output layers, it seems that other layer's weights got updated instead.

I have a minimized example with dummy data to present the problem:

```
import random

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Embedding
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


def policy_gradient_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.log(y_pred) * float(y_true))

# Define the model with 3 output layers (named 'a', 'b' and 'c').
input_layer = Input(shape=(4,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=10, output_dim=4)(input_layer)
lstm_layer = LSTM(4)(embedding_layer)
output_layers = [Dense(3, activation='softmax', name=name)(lstm_layer) for name in ['a', 'b', 'c']]
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layers)
model.compile(loss=[policy_gradient_loss] * 3, optimizer='adam', run_eagerly=True)

# Dummy input data.
input_data = np.array([[2, 3, 4, 5]])

# Create target data to reward only the 'b' output layer.
target_data = [np.array([0]) for _ in range(len(model._output_layers))]
target_data[1] = np.array([10]) 

# Save initial weights.
initial_weights = model.get_weights()

model.train_on_batch(input_data, y=target_data)

# Save weights after the learning.
updated_weights = model.get_weights()

# Compare the before-after weights.
for layer_idx, (layer_name, initial_w, updated_w) in enumerate(zip([layer.name for layer in model.layers], initial_weights, updated_weights)):
    if not tf.math.reduce_all(tf.equal(initial_w, updated_w)):
        print(f'The weights in layer {layer_idx} ({layer_name}). has changed.')
```

Result:

```
The weights in layer 0 (input_1). has changed.
The weights in layer 1 (embedding). has changed.
The weights in layer 2 (lstm). has changed.
The weights in layer 3 (a). has changed.
```

My expectation would be to get the layer 4. (output layer 'b') updated instead of layer 'a' (or at least beside 'a').

What am I missing? Is my expectation or my implementation wrong? (Or both...?)

Comment: Never use arrays as inputs for training in TF, they are used when you are dealing with multiple inputs/outputs...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thanks for your comment! Could you please explicate this a bit more? Is this a bad practice or do you see some actual error in the current setup? What to use instead? (btw I'm dealing here with multiple output layers)

Comment: just make the arrays `np.array`s, and you will see that errors start popping up

Comment: It's a newbie question, but how to do that? I guess you meant of  `target_data`, since `input_data` is an `np.array` already. If I update `target_data` as:

`target_data = np.array([np.array([0]), np.array([10]), np.array([0])])`
or
`target_data = np.array([[np.array([0]), np.array([10]), np.array([0])]])`
then I get Data cardinality or Incompatible shapes issue.

My original intention was to "tell" the model, that the `[2, 3, 4, 5]` input - that was generated e.g., with the b) output layer - was correct, hence update the weights of that layer only. Does this make sense?